# Как присвоить var другое значение?

Tags: android, kotlin, variable

Прохожу курс Google по android и Kotlin. Завис на проекте.
При нажатие на картинку вызывается функция clickLemonImage(). Она в теории должна присваивать lemonState новое значение, в зависимости от текущего.

```
private val SELECT = "select"
private val SQUEEZE = "squeeze" 
private val DRINK = "drink" 
private val RESTART = "restart"
private var lemonadeState = "select"

    lemonImage = findViewById(R.id.image_lemon_state)
    lemonImage!!.setOnClickListener {
        clickLemonImage()
    }


private fun clickLemonImage() {

    when (lemonadeState) {
        SELECT -> {
            lemonadeState == SQUEEZE
        }
        SQUEEZE -> {
            lemonadeState == DRINK
        }
        DRINK -> {
            lemonadeState == RESTART
        }
        RESTART -> {
            lemonadeState == SELECT
        }
    }
```

Comment: `==` -> `=` ...

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в [документации](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html), какие бывают операторы в Котлин.

Не путайте: `==` — это оператор равенства, а `=` — оператор присваивания.

Например, здесь происходит присваивание:

```kotlin
val number = 10
```

А здесь мы сначала сравниваем `number` с числом 10, а потом присваиваем полученное булево значение в переменную `isTen`:

```kotlin
val isTen = number == 10
```

Если хотите, можно поставить скобки и указать тип переменной:

```
val isTen: Boolean = (number == 10)
```